# Can i have publish Google +Hangout Support application with On the firewall

Tags: google-hangouts

I want to run my Google +Hangout application (XML file) with out ON fire wall ?

Without firewall ON how can i run the Google +Hangout support app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do and what is not working? Since a firewall might block a network traffic, without having a firewall on should mean everything would work without an issue.